# Is it safe to use c_str() as a parameter in std::exception?

Tags: c++, exception

Is it safe to pass `c_str()` as a parameter when constructing `std::exception`?  Please let me know if handling exceptions like this is a bad idea.  In my project all error messages are returned from a function as `std::string` and then thrown as a `std::exception`.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    try {
        std::string message="! Something went wrong.";
        throw std::exception(message.c_str());
    }
    catch (std::exception ex) {
        std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it's not, and I'm pretty sure this has been answered before.

Comment: In your question, you may want to explain in a few words why you are concerned that this may be a bad idea.

Comment: Setting aside the dangling pointer, `std::exception` doesn't have a constructor that takes an argument, except for its copy constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::exception` does not have a contructor that takes a `const char*` or a `std::string`.

`std::runtime_error` (and its descendants) does have constructors for both. And yes, it is perfectly safe (well, provided that memory is not low) to pass the `message.c_str()` pointer to this constructor. `std::runtime_error` will copy the character data into its own internal memory, allowing `message` to be destroyed after the exception is thrown.

If you want to throw `std::exception` itself with a string message, you will have to derive a custom class from it and implement your own string buffer for `what()` to return a pointer to.  In which case, you have to be careful not to return an invalid `const char*` pointer from `what()`.  `std::runtime_error` handles that for you, so you should derive from that instead.

Comment: ...and because it has a constructor taking `const char*` passing `message.c_str()` is wrong.

Comment: perfectly safe? `message` will be destroyed and the pointer returned from `c_str` will be dangling

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number you are wrong on both counts. `std::runtime_error` does not store the passed `char*` pointer as-is. It makes a copy of the data.

Comment: hm yes, would be strange if the constructor would not copy the string ;)